# Alpakka MongoDB - specify type in MongoSource

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I'm currently playing around with Akka Streams and the [Alpakka MongoDB connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/mongodb.html).

Is it possible to specify the type for `MongoSource`?

```
val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[TodoMongo]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
  private val todoCollection: MongoCollection[TodoMongo] = mongoDb
    .withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)
    .getCollection("todo")
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
val t: FindObservable[Seq[TodoMongo]] = todoCollection.find()
MongoSource(t) // Stuck here
```

But I get the following error:

```
Expected Observable[scala.Document], Actual FindObservable[Seq[TodoMongo]].
```

I can't find the correct documentation about this part.

Comment: `MongoSource(todoCollection.find())` is straight forward. what do you want to do with the intermediate `FindObservable `?

Comment: Or you can have a look at http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/streaming.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not published yet, but in Alpakka's master branch, [`MongoSource.apply`](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/master/mongodb/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/mongodb/scaladsl/MongoSource.scala) takes a type parameter:

```
object MongoSource {
  def apply[T](query: Observable[T]): Source[T, NotUsed] =
    Source.fromPublisher(ObservableToPublisher(query))
}
```

Therefore, with the upcoming 0.18 release of Alpakka, you'll be able to do the following:

```
val source: Source[TodoMongo, NotUsed] = MongoSource[TodoMongo](todoCollection.find())
```

Note that `source` here assumes that `todoCollection.find()` returns an `Observable[TodoMongo]`; adjust the types as needed.

In the meantime, you could simply add the above code manually. For example:

```
package akka.stream.alpakka.mongodb.scaladsl

import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.alpakka.mongodb.ObservableToPublisher
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import org.mongodb.scala.Observable

object MyMongoSource {
  def apply[T](query: Observable[T]): Source[T, NotUsed] =
    Source.fromPublisher(ObservableToPublisher(query))
}
```

Note that `MyMongoSource` is defined to reside in the `akka.stream.alpakka.mongodb.scaladsl` package (like `MongoSource`), because [`ObservableToPublisher`](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/v0.17/mongodb/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/mongodb/ObservableToPublisher.scala) is a package-private class. You would use `MyMongoSource` in the same way that you would use `MongoSource`:

```
val source: Source[TodoMongo, NotUsed] = MyMongoSource[TodoMongo](todoCollection.find())
```

Comment: Great answer. Was looking for something like this. But how to add the type manually with the following apply method of MongoSource? def apply(query: Observable[Document]): Source[Document, NotUsed]

Comment: Works great with Alpakka 0.18.