# Alpakka MongoDB - override MongoSource implementation

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I have similar problem as in [Alpakka MongoDB - specify type in MongoSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209062/alpakka-mongodb-specify-type-in-mongosource/49210426#49210426)

So I implemented my own `MongoSource` as was in the solution and used it:

```
object MyMongoSource {
  def apply[T](query: Observable[T]): Source[T, NotUsed] =
    Source.fromPublisher(ObservableToPublisher(query))
}

val source: Source[Book, NotUsed] = MyMongoSource[Book](mongoDb.books.find())
```

But `ObservableToPublisher` is `private class` so I get the following error:

```
object ObservableToPublisher in package mongodb cannot be accessed in package akka.stream.alpakka.mongodb
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Or you can have a look at http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/streaming.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `MyMongoSource` to be in the `akka.stream.alpakka.mongodb.scaladsl` package:

```
package akka.stream.alpakka.mongodb.scaladsl

import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.alpakka.mongodb.ObservableToPublisher
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import org.mongodb.scala.Observable

object MyMongoSource {
  def apply[T](query: Observable[T]): Source[T, NotUsed] =
    Source.fromPublisher(ObservableToPublisher(query))
}
```